# solidity sorting array - LIFO / FIFO

Tags: solidity, arrays, quorum

I am adding to an bytes32[] array via push().

When I traverse the array with for (uint i = 0; i < array.length; i++), This is First in First Out (FIFO) sequence right?

How can one perform a Last in First Out (LIFO)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have it as default inside the Solidity's default data structure but you can easily create a linked list and implement the LIFO algorithm.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract A {
    struct Node { 
        uint256 value;
        bytes32 nextNode;
    }
    bytes32 head;
    mapping(bytes32 => Node) list;

    function push(uint256 value) public {
        bytes32 key = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(value, head));
        Node memory newNode = Node(value, head);

        list[key] = newNode;
        head = key;
    }

    function headValue() public view returns(uint256) {
        require(head != 0);

        return list[head].value;
    }

    function sum() public view returns(uint256) {
        bytes32 current = head;
        uint256 total = 0;
        while (current != 0) {
            total += list[current].value;
            current = list[current].nextNode;
        }

        return total;
    }

}
```

Comment: Or he can simply do `for (uint i = array.length; i > 0; i--)`, and handle `array[i - 1]` at every iteration. This dude hasn't mentioned anything about removing an arbitrary item from the array, so a linked-list implementation seems like a huge overkill in this case.